# Reactjs (Create React App, CRA) npm run build failed and throw Error: ... envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: reactjs

When I try to do a build (npm run build) in the Create React app, it is aborted with the error "Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The issue was caused by the latest (17+) version of NodeJS.
I simply just uninstalled the current version. Went to their website and downloaded the recommended version (16.14.0). My project was working absolutely fine after that.
You can download the recommended version from their official [website](https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.14.0/node-v16.14.0-x64.msi)

[image: Node JS versions]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This Error is caused by the new version of node 17.x

Add a `--openssl-legacy-provider` to your build script:

Open the package.json file in your root folder.

Change

`"build": "react-scripts build"`

To

`"build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"`